# XPATH WEB PAGE ALL SELECTORS RETURN NULL

Tags: xpath

I am new in stack overflow, I'am usuing a excel google sheet with Function "importfromweb" and Xpath.

I am trying to extract the telephone number from this page below trough Xpath, but the result is **#ALL_SELECTORS_RETURN_NULL**

**Web Page:**
https://www.milanuncios.com/datos-contacto/?usePhoneProxy=0&from=list&includeEmail=false&id=351684334

**Xpath**=/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()

**Code in the Google sheet:**
=**IMPORTFROMWEB**([https://www.milanuncios.com/datos-contacto/?usePhoneProxy=0&from=list&includeEmail=false&id=351684334;/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()](https://www.milanuncios.com/datos-contacto/?usePhoneProxy=0&from=list&includeEmail=false&id=351684334;/html/body/div%5B1%5D/div/div%5B2%5D/div%5B2%5D/text()))

Where is the problem?
With the Name I have the result, but with the telephone number is impossible!

Thanks for your help!

[The result is of XPATH: **#ALL_SELECTORS_RETURN_NULL**][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJEXX.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The community has noticed some quality problems with your post. Please read the [guide on how to ask good guestions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate JS rendering to get the value.

[image]

XPath :

```
//div[@class="telefonos"]
```

Formula in C5 :

```
=IMPORTFROMWEB(C1;C2;B3:C3)
```

Or retrieve it with `IMPORTXML`. In C8 :

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(C1;"//script[contains(text(),'getTrackingPhone')]");"getTrackingPhone\((\d+)")
```

Comment: The first solution with IMPORTFROMWEB does not work!                                    
The Second solution with REGEXEXTRACT and IMPORTXML WORKS FANTASTIC! Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Great ! `IMPORTFROMWEB` works on my side. That's odd... Please accept the best answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Since this shows up in Google, the best current solution is to use the built-in function IMPORTHTML. No add-on is necessary.